# Random Variables. A Probability Question.

Tags: probability, random-variables

We have the folloing problem in my probability class, and I want to know if I have outlined it correctly.

In a Kingdom there are $3$ prisoners; $A,B,$ and $C$. The king says that two are condemned to death, but they don't know who. Prisoner $A$ asks the guardian, who knows the answer, to tell him one of the other prisoners that is going to die. The guardian tells him $B$. Now $A$ says that, rather he or $C$ die, therefore they both have $50\%$ chance of not dying. You may suppose that the chance of not being condemned is $\frac{1}{3}$, and that if the guardian knows that $A$ is not going to die then the probability of him telling $A$ that $B$ or $C$ is going to die is $\frac{1}{2}$.

The problem says that we should outline it in terms of random variables and check the statement that $A$ made.

So, what I did is:

Let $X_1,X_2 : \Omega := \{ A,B,C\} \to [0,1]$, where $X_1$ denotes the chance of not being killed and $X_2$ denotes what $A$ knows about the death of the other ones.

In this sense, we get:

- $\mathbb{P}(X_1=A)=\mathbb{P}(X_1=C)= \mathbb{P}(X_1=B)= \frac{1}{3}$.
- $\mathbb{P}(X_2=A)=\mathbb{P}(X_2=A)= 0, \mathbb{P}(X_2=B)= 1$.

Now we want to know:
$$\mathbb{P}(X_1=A \vert X_2=B).$$
And we know that:
 $\mathbb{P}(X_1=A \vert X_2=B)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(X_2=B \vert X_1=A)\mathbb{P}(X_1=A)}{\mathbb{P}(X_2=B)}. $$

Which implies that: $$\mathbb{P}(X_1=A \vert X_2=B)= \frac{1}{6}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Under the "usual" interpretation of this problem (which is a well-known one), $C$ has a $2/3$ chance of living, and $A$ has a $1/3$ chance of living.  There are a number of ways to reason this out, but one fairly straightforward way is as follows:

Before the guard spoke, $A$ had a $1/3$ chance of living.  Now, the guard could always name *some* other prisoner who would die, since either $B$ or $C$ (or both) will die.  So any answer from him cannot affect $A$'s probability of living, which continues to be $1/3$.  However, since $B$ is known to die, $C$'s probability of living must be $1-1/3 = 2/3$.

If you want it in terms of random variables, one can represent the situation symbolically as follows:

Let $X$ be the prisoner who will live.  Prior to the guard's statement, we have $P(X = A) = P(X = B) = P(X = C) = 1/3$.  Let $Y$ be the guard's answer to $A$'s question.  We can write

$$
P(Y = B \mid X = A) = 1/2 \\
P(Y = B \mid X = B) = 0 \\
P(Y = B \mid X = C) = 1
$$

We also know, by symmetry, that $P(Y = B) = P(Y = C) = 1/2$.  We therefore can write, using Bayes's Law,

$$
P(X = A \mid Y = B) = \frac{P(Y = B \mid X = A)P(X = A)}{P(Y = B)}
                    = \frac{(1/2)(1/3)}{1/2} = \frac{1}{3}
$$

and also

$$
P(X = C \mid Y = B) = \frac{P(Y = B \mid X = C)P(X = C)}{P(Y = B)}
                    = \frac{(1)(1/3)}{1/2} = \frac{2}{3}
$$

which are the same values we reasoned out above.

See also [Monty Haul problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem).

Comment: Thank you very much, but I don't understand one thing. How can we ensure that $P(Y=B)=P(Y=C)=1/2$?